# Format Code for European currency number format in Open XML without symbol

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

> My application is developed in C# MVC and I am using Open XML for
>   Exporting Grid's data in Excel Sheet. Grid has various columns which
>   holds Amount fields. I have two buttons on page, one is "NA" for north
>   american format and another is "EU" for European format. Both button
>   exports excel sheet.

---

> When "NA" is pressed exported excel Amount column values are converted
>   as following and **working good**,

```
1000000  ----------> 1,000,000  (Format Code used : #,##0)
```

> But when "EU" is pressed exported excel amount values are not
>   converted as per expectation and **is not working**.

```
1000000  ----------> 1000000.0  (Format Code used : #.##0)
```

> In Open XML, I configured stylesheet.xml file as

```
<x:numFmt numFmtId="169" formatCode="[>=1000]#,##0" />   // This works
<x:numFmt numFmtId="170" formatCode="[>=1000]#.##0" />   // This doesn't work
```

> Do anyone has any suggestions here to solve this. I even try to change
>   the Cell Formatting in Excel Sheet for European Currency through
>   Custom Format option but that also doesn't work.
>
> My expected result is following which I couldn't achieved.

```
1000000  ----------->  1.000.000
```

Comment: You are trying to use `.` as thousand separator?

Comment: In Europe continent, commas(,) are replaced with Period(.) to show thousand's places in number and Comma is used once at the end to show decimal places. In my case I do not need decimal values.

Comment: The `formatCode`s in the XML are always EN_US. They are never locale dependent. The Excel version which will interpret the XML converts it into the appropriate locale version.

Comment: Yes '.' as thousand separator

Comment: @AxelRichter : So can we achieve this otherwise....? Do Microsoft has different version of Excel for Europe continent?

Comment: The problem is that inside the format string `.` always mean decimal point and `,` means thousand separator, which then are replaced with the actual symbols from the current culture. If (for some reason) you want using a fixed symbol you have to embed it as string like `"#\\.###\\.###\\.##0"`

Comment: But reading your post, you don't really need separate `NA` and `EU` exports. Just use `#,##0` and it will show correctly.

Comment: "Do Microsoft has different versions of Excel" Yes. There are different language versions of Excel and Excel follows the locale settings of the Windows operating system. So there is no need for different `formatCode`s in the XML.

Comment: @IvanStoev : "#\\.###\\.###\\.##0" -- this does not work for 1000000. It gives **1000.000** but i need to show **1.000.000**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the decimal/thousands separators per workbook or per worksheet or per cell range.

You have to use the `[>=1000]#,##0` format.

How it is shown depends on system's locale settings or on the Excel's settings for separator (File/Excel Options/Advanced).

If the exported data is the same both for NA and EU, you can leave one button for export. The users usually have the separators set up to ones they are used to.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eaa4c7f6-197a-4b33-bc5f-20896e5a7e3a/workbook-or-worksheet-specific-decimal-separator?forum=excel

Comment: Can you suggest any custom format to display the figures as I require, like 1000000 converted to 1.000.000

Comment: @devgal If you want the cells' content to be number, there is no way to control separator (`.` or `,`). It is not stored anywhere in the spreadsheet. Otherwise you can have the numbers as strings.